# Understanding page copying in C

Tags: c, performance, gnu, glibc, memcpy

I heard that `memcpy` was a very efficient algorithm for copying data.  To try to learn some lessons for my code, I decided to study its implementation in GNU.  However, for large memory blocks, it does some checks, and then [calls a PAGE_COPY_FWD macro](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/generic/pagecopy.h)-- which I cannot find defined anywhere.

Last link of the source code of mem_cpy says:

```
System-specific pagecopy.h files should define these macros and then
  #include this file:

  ...

  PAGE_COPY_FWD (dstp, srcp, nbytes_left, nbytes)
```

Two questions:

1) How can I find the implementation of this macro? (anywhere-- either on my machine, or on someone else's-- even if that means I have to read the assembly code.)

2) What do I have to include to be able to call this macro directly, i.e. without going through memcpy first?

Comment: Thanks.  Hmm, wonder what the downvote is about...

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you're looking a the wrong `memcpy()`. The real ones are mostly all assembler. (e.g. [amd64](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S#L56)). `PAGE_COPY_FWD` seems only to exist for [Mach](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/mach/pagecopy.h#L26) (where it calls `__vm_copy()`). And that one sounds fishily like OS/X `vm_copy()` that fiddles with the page map to COW-duplicate a page.

Comment: @lurker -- Oops, I called it a function in 1 place.  I'll go edit it out right now.  But the macro defined in the header file is *not* PAGE_COPY_FWD, but PAGE_COPY_FWD_MAYBE.  Which in turn *calls* the PAGE_COPY_FWD macro, which I can't find.

Comment: The implementation of `PAGE_COPY_FWD` must be in another header file in the files associated with that project.

Comment: @dhke Is there any way to get access to an assembler memcpy?  I am just curious if I can use the page copy command directly for my programs.

Comment: @lurker Since you deleted and reposted, I'll post my answer after your comment.  How can I find *any* project, where it is defined?  That's the essence of my question.

Comment: @Alex macros are not "called". They are not functions. They are text substitution, before even compiling.

Comment: @Alex See link in comment. For glibc, those are all in `sysdeps/<arch>/memcpy*.S`

Comment: @dhke Wow, never knew comments can include links...  And I have a couple thousand combined reputation already...  You can post those links as an answer, and I would accept.

Comment: @Alex link from a comment with `[description](URL)` without space padding (or monospace formatting which I used to defeat the link mechanism for this example).

Comment: You can thank Roland McGrath for adding * string/Makefile (distribute): Add pagecopy.h on 1995-02-21 See: [**glibc commit**](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=67a87b936eaab25dc983e979e5a548256d1a527a)

Comment: @Alex NMDV  Good luck

Comment: What for? Fast memory copy is hardware & optimisation dependant as in many compilers it one of the built in functions. So compiler can inline it, call it or replace by number of reads and writes depending on the size  and compiler options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this definition of `PAGE_COPY_FWD`

```
#define PAGE_COPY_FWD(dstp, srcp, nbytes_left, nbytes)  \ 
     ((nbytes_left) = ((nbytes) - \
      (__vm_copy (__mach_task_self (),  \
       (vm_address_t) srcp, trunc_page (nbytes), \
        (vm_address_t) dstp) == KERN_SUCCESS    \
                 ? trunc_page (nbytes) \
                 : 0)))
```

Found it here https://www.sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/mach/pagecopy.h

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

**DESCRIPTION**

The vm_copy function copies a source region to a destination region within the same task's virtual memory. It is semantically equivalent to vm_read followed by vm_write. The destination region can overlap the source region.

The destination region must already be allocated. The source region must be readable, and the destination region must be writable.

in linux copy_page_64.S, this is implemented using prefetch instruction, to speedup the transfer.